# Traversing a binary tree using boolean logic

Tags: c#, if-statement, boolean

Let me start off by saying sorry if the title is wrong.

I am being taught Binary Tree Traversal I've been given some of the code, I am really struggling to understand the logic in using the if/else statements and the boolean logic.

I have to traverse the tree using postorder, preorder and inorder methods.

The preorderTraversal method is all ready done and working.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

The Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace BinaryTree
{
class BinaryTree<T>
{
   class BinaryTreeNode
    {
        public BinaryTreeNode Left;
        public BinaryTreeNode Right;
        public BinaryTreeNode Parent;
        public T Data;
        public Boolean processed;

        public BinaryTreeNode()
        {
            Left = null;
            Right = null;
            Parent = null;
            processed = false;
        }
    }

    BinaryTreeNode Root;
    Comparison<T> CompareFunction;

    public BinaryTree(Comparison<T> theCompareFunction)
    {
        Root = null;
        CompareFunction = theCompareFunction;
    }

    public static int CompareFunction_Int(int left, int right)
    {
        return left - right;
    }

    public void preorderTraversal()
    {
        if (Root != null)
        {
            BinaryTreeNode currentNode = Root;
            Boolean process = true;
            int nodesProcessed = 0;
            while (nodesProcessed != 11)
            {
                if (process)
                {
                    Console.Write(currentNode.Data.ToString());
                    currentNode.processed = true;
                    nodesProcessed = nodesProcessed +1;
                }
                process = true;

                if (currentNode.Left != null && currentNode.Left.processed == false)
                {
                    currentNode = currentNode.Left;
                }
                else if (currentNode.Right != null && currentNode.Right.processed ==            
                false)
                {
                    currentNode = currentNode.Right;
                }
                else if (currentNode.Parent != null)
                {
                    currentNode = currentNode.Parent;
                    process = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is no tree to process");
        }
    }

    public void postorderTraversal()
    {
        if (Root != null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is no tree to process");
        }
    }
    public void inorderTraversal()
    {
        if (Root != null)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There is no tree to process");
        }
    }        
     public static int CompareFunction_String(string left, string right)
    {
        return left.CompareTo(right);
    }

    public void Add(T Value)
    {
        BinaryTreeNode child = new BinaryTreeNode();
        child.Data = Value;

        if (Root == null)
        {
            Root = child;
        }
        else
        {

            BinaryTreeNode Iterator = Root;
            while (true)
            {

                int Compare = CompareFunction(Value, Iterator.Data);

                if (Compare <= 0)
                    if (Iterator.Left != null)
                    {

                        Iterator = Iterator.Left;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Iterator.Left = child;
                        child.Parent = Iterator;
                        break;
                    }

                if (Compare > 0)
                    if (Iterator.Right != null)
                    {

                        Iterator = Iterator.Right;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Iterator.Right = child;
                        child.Parent = Iterator;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    public bool Find(T Value)
    {
        BinaryTreeNode Iterator = Root;
        while (Iterator != null)
        {
            int Compare = CompareFunction(Value, Iterator.Data);

            if (Compare == 0) return true;
            if (Compare < 0)
            {

                Iterator = Iterator.Left;
                continue;
            }

            Iterator = Iterator.Right;
        }
        return false;
    }

    BinaryTreeNode FindMostLeft(BinaryTreeNode start)
    {
        BinaryTreeNode node = start;
        while (true)
        {
            if (node.Left != null)
            {
                node = node.Left;
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        return node;
    }


    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new BinaryTreeEnumerator(this);
    }



    class BinaryTreeEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        BinaryTreeNode current;
        BinaryTree<T> theTree;
        public BinaryTreeEnumerator(BinaryTree<T> tree)
        {
            theTree = tree;
            current = null;
        }


        public bool MoveNext()
        {

            if (current == null)
                current = theTree.FindMostLeft(theTree.Root);
            else
            {

                if (current.Right != null)
                    current = theTree.FindMostLeft(current.Right);
                else
                {

                    T CurrentValue = current.Data;

                    while (current != null)
                    {
                        current = current.Parent;
                        if (current != null)
                        {
                            int Compare = theTree.CompareFunction(current.Data,                    
CurrentValue);                            
                         if (Compare < 0) continue;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (current != null);
        }

        public T Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (current == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                return current.Data;
            }
        }

        object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (current == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
                return current.Data;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose() { }

        public void Reset() { current = null; }

    }
}

class TreeTest
{
    static BinaryTree<int> Test = new BinaryTree<int>                                                                
(BinaryTree<int>.CompareFunction_Int);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Build the tree
        Test.Add(5);
        Test.Add(2);
        Test.Add(1);
        Test.Add(3);
        Test.Add(3); // Duplicates are OK
        Test.Add(4);
        Test.Add(6);
        Test.Add(10);
        Test.Add(7);
        Test.Add(8);
        Test.Add(9);
        // Test if we can find values in the tree

        for (int Lp = 1; Lp <= 10; Lp++)

            Console.WriteLine("Find ({0}) = {1}", Lp, Test.Find(Lp));

        // Test if we can find a non-existing value
        Console.WriteLine("Find (999) = {0}", Test.Find(999));

        // Iterate over all members in the tree -- values are returned in sorted order
        foreach (int value in Test)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Preorder traversal");
        Test.preorderTraversal();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're asking, and you've posted a wall of code here. Binary tree traversal is a well covered subject, with information available all over the internet, as well. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) isn't a bad place to start. If you have a specific question about your homework, feel free to ask it, but "I don't understand," isn't specific enough to be answerable.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot after seeing that wall, I'm sure winter is coming ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, maybe some nice animations with option to traverse it the way you like, and add and delete so you can have your own example might help: Look at [this site](http://www.qmatica.com/DataStructures/Trees/AVL/AVLTree.html)

Or maybe CS animation with voice over ... look [here](http://www.csanimated.com/animation.php?t=Binary_search_tree).

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look, In all truth we were given the code; told it was being used with a boolean and to use the boolean logic with if/else statements to traverse the binary tree in the right order depending on the method (preorder, postorder, inorder)

Comment: Both will be helpful. You're question is way to wide to answer, so maybe you should read some, and improve the question and make it more precise.

Comment: Have you any suggestions for resources to look at as I've spent some time looking around the web (and through several books I have), but cannot find anything like what we've been given.

Comment: go to the first link I've posted in my answer. Select the type of traversal you have, look at the algorithm run. Then select the next type of traversal, look at the algorithm run ... that should give you an idea of the differences. from there to code it's a short way ...

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion), Luke. (Then it's just a matter in what order you visit (and process) the left subtree, right subtree, or the current node itself.)

Comment: We were given a quick introduction to Recursion, so I think I'll have to have a better look to understand where I need to go from here!!!